# How can I upload file with 800MB size and rar extension grocery crud

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, grocery-crud, rar

I need to upload a file with `rar` extension and `800MB` size, I add into `$config['grocery_crud_file_upload_allow_file_types']` the `rar` extension, and works but only in files with 3MB. 
I change mi `php.ini` and put `upload_max_filesize = 1024M` , change `$config['grocery_crud_file_upload_max_file_size'] = 1024MB` and add in my grocerycrud `mimes.php`  `'rar'   =>  array('application/x-rar-compressed','application/x-rar', 'application/rar', 'application/octet-stream')`

 I can see the progres bar but when reach 100% I do not see tha name of the file that it always show, or any error. I `save` but in my database do not save the `url`.
Please help, I need to upload 800MB. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the `max_post_size` in `php.ini`?

Comment: did you restart your server after doing changes in php.ini file?

Comment: post_max_size=1024M, I do not remember, but I know that someone has to be bigger than the other, i do not konow if this is the problem

Comment: @Mary ... $config['allowed_types'] = 'zip|rar';     R U Config this ....

Comment: I think that is the problem, I restar my server when I change upload_mas_file size, I think I forgotted restar hen I change post_max_size

Comment: I think that is the problem, I restar my server when I change upload_mas_file size, I think I forgotted restar hen I change post_max_size

Comment: @Mary Stop the server and again restart then settings are apply ..

Comment: @RïshïKêsh Kümar, I make a search but I do not found $config['allowed_types']

Comment: @Mary    You have Declare in Your .. Controller ...  $config['upload_path'] = './img/header/';   
$config['*'] = 'rar|zip';
$config['max_size'] = '2048000';
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE                ...... Like THis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Settings For for allowed type:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'zip|rar';
```

> Replace the mime.php configuration for zip and rar to:

```
'zip'  =>  array('application/x-zip', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed','application/force-download','application/octet-stream'),
'rar'  =>  array('application/x-rar', 'application/rar','application/x-rar-compressed','application/force-download','application/octet-stream'),
```

**In your php.ini**

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
```

**and**

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 1000M
```

**and  You can also change limits in**

> .htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 1000M
```

**NOTE::**

> Please Restart The Server After Edit In `.php`  `mime.php`  `.htaccess`